# FTP:Move file from one directory to another.Exception:350 File exists, ready for new name

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Im uploading file (orig.txt) to the FTP Directory say Test/test4,before uploading im checking whether that file exists in the test4,If yes then im moving that file to archive folder and then go for uploading the file to the test4 Dir.
While moving to archive folder im getting this exception.  "350 File exists, ready for new name.".
Below is the code

```
if (CheckFileExists("ftp://1.1.1.4:1//Test/test4/orig.txt") //separate method which returns boolean
{
   FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://1.1.1.4:1//Test/test4/orig.txt")
   req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
   req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user","pass");
   req.KeepAlive = true;
   req.Timeout = -1;
   // Code  ...if file exists in archive folder path then rename string fileName i.e example orig.txt to new_orig.txt
   //req.RenameTo = ".../"+ ArchiveFolderPath + "/"+ fileName ;
   req.RenameTo = ".../TestDirectory/Test2/test1/new_orig.txt"; 
   try
   {
     FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
     WriteToLogFile("Moved File to Archive Folder");
     response.Close();
   }
   catch (WebException ex)
   {
     FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
     WriteToLogFile("Status Code : "+response.StatusCode.ToString() + ",FTP Status Desc: " + response.StatusDescription);
     response.Close();
   }
}

// Actual Path of Archive Folder = "ftp://1.1.1.4:1//TestDirectory/Test2/test1/"
// File to be uploded ="ftp://1.1.1.4:1//Test/test4/"
```

Where am i going wrong? Please Help

Comment: the problem seems expected. you check if it exists, then you try and put a file to orig.txt but move it to test1/new_orig.txt if it existed..... but orig.txt already exists so its telling you what you already know.

Comment: @BugFinder :Thanks for the reply,but couldnt understand.Can u pls explain. im changing the filename (string) before moving it since already a file with same name exists in archive folder.

Comment: if you are sure then the only other thing it can be is that ".../TestDirectory/Test2/test1/new_orig.txt" also already exists..

Comment: @BugFinder no I checked it doesn't exists.

Comment: well, theres only 2 files involved, and you're sure .. so at which line is it telling you it already exists?

Comment: @BugFinder : After req.RenameTo when it executes req.GetResponse

Comment: What is `.../`?

Comment: On some systems it goes back 2 levels.. i was about to ask if this system supports it...

Comment: @BugFinder :I tried replacing ".../TestDirectory/" with "/TestDirectory/"  and also assigning the full path ,but dint work.